# Nvidia x server setting no specific option

Tags: nvidia, resolution

I just freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04 and did only 4 things:

1)

`$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-340`

2)

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates nvidia-settings-updates
```

3) Went to Software & Updates/Additional drivers and chosen

> Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.32 from nvidia-340 (open source)

I had to do part 3 because after part 1 I had driver version 304

Now to the main part. I cant set up custom resolution. When  I had Ubuntu 12.04 year ago there was option in Nvidia x server setting called "Add custom resolution" or something like that and it was alright. Now this option is gone. How can I change/add custom resolution?

Comment: There is a overscan / underscan slider in nvidia-settings this is the same thing

Comment: Also open nvidia-settings and choose x server config then click advanced ant the options are right there

Comment: I have only underscan option. I cannot go beyond resolution I already have. Maximum resolution on the list is 1360x768 and I need 1440x900. What is important my LCD monitor is detected as CRT 1 and no name because (I think) I have it connected to DVI port on my card through VGA-DVI converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open this file

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

And find the section "Module" and make the appropriate lines look like this

```
Load "glx"
# Load "dri"
# Load "GLcore"
```

Comment: When I change ViewPortIn on 1440x900 its ok. But in ViewPortIn when i change from 1024x768+0+0 to 1440x900+0+0 it change itself back to 1024x768+0+0 when i click elsewhere. I still hit Apply button but I think image is a little blurry. I remember changing timing to gtf made it alright but it was in good'ol'days when I had "Add custom resolution" option (then there was this option)

Comment: please thell me the resolution you would like to set and the native resolution of your monitor and I will explain it for you

Comment: Native resolution: 1400x900

Comment: I want: 1440x900

Comment: But you only get 1024x768, is this your problem

Comment: 1360x768;1152x864;1024x768;800x600 and the list go on downwards

Comment: Can you remove all drivers and the edgers PPA and just use the driver from ubuntu ppa, do you need instructions ?

Comment: also try this in terminal xrandr -s 1440x900

Comment: Yeah, please give me easy instruction what to do step by step

Comment: First run xrandr -s 1440x900 please

Comment: I used this command (xrandr) and some part of my screen started flashing and, it stoped in circa 4 sec and then its back to normal: good 1440x900 but blurry

Comment: do you meen it worked ?

Comment: I had 1440x900 before xrandr by using this ViewPortIn option. The problem is that screen is now blurry. I fixed it once when i had Add Custom Resolution option (it was in there) by settting timing to GTF. Now i dont know how to fix this problem

Comment: I dont have enough rep to start a chat

Comment: As for gtf command: 
usage: gtf x y refresh [-v|--verbose] [-f|--fbmode] [-x|--xorgmode]

            x : the desired horizontal resolution (required)
            y : the desired vertical resolution (required)
      refresh : the desired refresh rate (required)
 -v|--verbose : enable verbose printouts (traces each step of the computation)
  -f|--fbmode : output an fbset(8)-style mode description
 -x|--xorgmode : output an Xorg-style mode description (this is the default
                if no mode description is requested)

Comment: And xrandr:
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1440 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       60.0     59.8  
   1152x864       60.0  
   800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2  
   680x384        60.0     59.8  
   640x480        59.9  
   512x384        60.0  
   400x300        72.2  
   320x240        60.1

Comment: TV-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Comment: I apologise please run the gtf again I made a spelling mistake

Comment: # 1440x900 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 55.92 kHz; pclk: 106.47 MHz
  Modeline "1440x900_60.00"  106.47  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 901 904 932  -HSync +Vsync

Comment: http://imgur.com/bhmCJEa,un7W8Pc#0
There are screens of my Nvidia settings

Comment: Go to nvidia settings then from the left choose "X server Xvideo settings" and tell me what it says in brackets, mine says HDMI0

Comment: CRT-1 (DVI-I-1)

Comment: I jus mate a edit use this onet

Comment: Ive tried to reboot with this condig file set in Device on "CRT-1", "DVI-1" and "DVI-I-1". Nothing helped. I still have 1024x768

Comment: Is it listed in nvidia settings

Comment: DVI-I-1 If this is exactly what that screen said use this I thought it was a typo

Comment: One other thing can you go to software sources and restricted drivers and install nvidia-current-updates, or make sure you have this one installed

Comment: i have nvidia 340.32 (ive chosen it from Software and Drivers/Additional Drivers) and nvidia site says its the latest driver

Comment: OK we can try something else I will edit the answer please delete the file you made in terminal with sudo rm /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf

Comment: Updatet the answer

Comment: After runing sudo Xorg -configure i got:    (EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Server is already active for display 0
 If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock
 and start again.
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
  at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE)

Comment: and xorg.conf is empty

Comment: I made a mistake try to open the file again in a second if still blank do this,Go to nvidia settings where you change the resolution and choose save to x config file, if save location is blank enter /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Comment: Also please thell me was the correct device DVI-I-1 or DVI-1

Comment: When i go to X server Xvideo Settings i have only this: CRT-1 (DVI-I-1). And your method doesnt help. Ive tried with DVI-1 and DVI-I-1 in section Device. You think the problem is that i have VGA monitor connected do DVI port in graphic card through VGA->DVI?

Comment: Mabey I could not say, I will re edit a final version for you, make sure to make a xorg.conf in nvidia settings

Comment: I have this file, because i saved it from nvidia settings to given location.

Comment: We can try one last thing, do this in terminal sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf Then make a new one from settings and find this line Option "metamodes" "1360x768_60 +0+0" and make it this Option         "metamodes" "1440x900_60 +0+0"

Comment: Save and you must reboot

Comment: I also found this I dont know if this is working or not but you can try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihv62nK4s7M

Comment: It doesnt work.  I'll give a try to adding modeline line for my native resolution. Thank you for trying.

Comment: Here is the site with the info I was using, please review it you seem like you could understand it, it really should work. If I think of any thing I will post it here

Comment: http://samuelmartin.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/enabling-resolutions-in-ubuntu-12-04-lubuntu-12-04/

Comment: Can I ask do you use a vga port in your monitor and does it have a dvi or hdmi port

Comment: A VGA cable may very well be your issue if you consult the following chart of types of vga and the max resolutions, you will see only high end VGA cables support a resolution this high http://www.reinmedical.com/en/knowledge-technology/monitor-resolutions-overview.html

Comment: If you dont have a dvi port in your monitor you should use a dvi cable and then convert this to vga at the end

Comment: I have VGA port on the monitor and DVI on graphic card. I use VGA cable and i have VGA->DVI port converter attached to graphic card. Shall I use DVI cable and converter attached to monitor?

Comment: I believe based on research that the VGA cable may be your issue, try swamping it for a DVI cable and convert that to VGA at the monitor, your converter should work fine so you wont need a new one of those, just find the cheapest dvi you can ( the min max resolution of DVI is 1920x1200) and I think this will work for you.

Comment: And i dont know whether you realise, i already have 1440x900 resolution set. I did it by changing ViewPortIn value from 1024x768 to 1440x900. But the problem is that screen is now a little blurry.

Comment: Also, I fresly installed Ubuntu today. I was changing OS version. I had 32 bit yesterday and I have 64 bit today. I didnt helped anyway.

Comment: Try this viewportin=1024x768 viewportout=1440x900 and see if it is less blurry

Comment: I still think the blurriness is caused by the VGA cable, if it cant output 1440x900, then when you force it it will just stretch it to fit the screen (the same effect you get when you run a youtube video full screen and it looks crap)

Comment: Hmmmm, but previously i was using same setting (cables and ports) and everything was ok (image was sharp). I just had to change option "timing" to gtf in nvidia-settings. Now i dont have this option because its gone along with "Add custom resolution".

Comment: I think eselect is option strickly for gentoo. I dont have such command on Ubuntu

Comment: I think you are right, I also think I worked out how to do the same thing manualy. Updating the answer..